# What is the significance of the "Six" in the All Terrain MegaCaliber Six (AT-M6) walker's name?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Episode VIII *The Last Jedi* introduced the [All Terrain MegaCaliber Six](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/All_Terrain_MegaCaliber_Six) (AT-M6) walker, which is an upgraded AT-AT. According to Wookieepedia, the walker's name comes from the "MegaCaliber Six" turbolaser cannon mounted on its back. **What is the significance of the "Six" in the name?** Is it the sixth version of the weapon? Does it quantify the cannon's output power (e.g. 6 MW) or something similar? Something else?

Comment: Could be a reference to the [Caliber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caliber) of the turbolaser, e.g. - the MegaCaliber Six turbolaser has a 6 inch diameter on the barrel of the weapon.